# The : operator for DQL queries

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p
FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
WHERE p.price > :price
ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
```

I am a little bit confused about the colon and the different places it can be used in a query. 
I think :price is just declaring price as a local variable which will then be replace by 19.99 during runtime.

1) Is the aforementioned assumption correct?

2) Are there some other places you see the ':' in DQL so I don't confuse it with its other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon `:` operator is used for prepared statements. It is like the `$` character for variable naming in PHP, but dedicated to Doctrine.

You might notice the `AcmeStoreBundle:Product` has a colon inside of it too, but this is a Symfony feature where you can define the Bundle that the Entity belongs to. There's no other way to use the operator in Doctrine.

Answer (score 3):

`1) Is the aforementioned assumption correct?`

Yes, `:price` is in fact a `parameter` which is used to avoid ugly codes like this :

```
"SELECT ... WHERE p.price > " . $price
```

Instead, use the parameter notation, and after call the `setParamter()` method :

```
->setParameter('price', '19.99'); << Without prefix
```

[More info from the doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-and-positional-parameters)

`2) Are there some other places you see the ':' in DQL so I don't confuse it with its other functions.`

I don't know for that :)